# Load php file on the same page

Tags: php

I have a problem with my webpage.

I have this webpage where the user can input his/her name into input box. Then by clicking go, what was inputted will be displayed on the same page.

How can I make this possible with php?

Here are my codes:

index.html

```
<form action="display.php" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="textinput">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

display.php:

```
<?php
    $msg=$_POST['textinput'];
    echo ($msg);
?>
```

Comment: One option is to use AJAX to HTTP POST the form data to your server/php script. Then you can repopulate your HTML page with the data that was sent if the POST was successful and an error message if it wasn't. Is this what you are trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

`$_POST['textinput']`

instead of

`$POST_['textinput']`

EDIT:

display.php

```
<?php if(isset($_POST['form_submit']))
    {
        if(isset($_POST['textinput']))
        {
            $msg = $_POST['textinput'];
        }
        else
        {
            $msg = 'The form was submitted, but the text box was empty';
        }
        echo $msg;
    } 
    else
    {
        echo"NOTHING HERE";
    }
?>
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="textinput" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="form_submit" />
</form>
```

Create the display.php file and put all the above code in it. Hopefully this should work. 
Enjoy.

Comment: No problem. SO it that your error fixed now, or are you still getting problems?

Comment: The codes above works. But during submission of form the display.php is displayed on a different page. What I want is to display the message on the same page, right below the form.

Comment: Thanks mate, this perfectly works. I have one more question, I noticed that when I click the submit button twice it doesn't display the textinput value again. I want that everytime the user clicks the submit button php will display again and again.

Comment: DO you mean twice in a row, or submitting the form separately twice? This may be because you may have left the text field empty. I've updated my answer to accommodate for that (obviously you can add validation etc to ensure the field isn't empty)

Answer (score 0):

```
<form method="post" action="display.php">
```

try

```
$_post['textinput']
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want something to happen at the same screen you shouldn't use php. This would mean an unnecessary connection to the server.

You could use JQuery:

```
ENTER YOUR NAME <input type="text" id="input1" />
<button onclick="$('#input2').val($('#input1').val());">GO</button>
<input type="text" id="input2" />
```

Make sure to load the JQuery library.

Comment: I need to use php because I will be displaying more details from the database but on the same page.